# Passing object from TestSuite to a TestCase in juint4

Tags: java, junit

I want to pass an object (not just a string or integer) from a TestSuite to all the TestCases.
In previous junit versions I could have pass an argument to the constructor before calling   `testSuite.addTest(new TestCase(someObject))`
How can I do it now using the annotation style?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to?  Can you elaborate on what you want to accomplish?  (I can think of some hacks like setting static state or passing in a class name that loads the object you need.)  But I can't imagine what you are trying to accomplish so there may well be a better way.  The common use is Parameterized Test Cases which have built in support and don't need to be passed via the TestSuite

Comment: I'm using embedded-tomcat in my application. I don't want to restart tomcat on every test case since starting tomcat takes ~30 seconds. So I wanted to share the tomcat between my tests, as its state doesn't change during all tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make that a singleton with lazy loading.  The first test calls TomcatHelper.getSharedTomcat() which creates the shared state.  The second tests calls TomcatHelper.getSharedTomcat() which returns the same instances before.

I don't think your example is extreme enough to be worth mucking with runners/hacking JUnit to do something non-traditional.

Comment: This was my thought also. The only problem I had is how to shutdown tomcat in the end of all tests. I found that I can use @AfterClass in the SuiteClass in order to do stuff after all the tests are ended.

Comment: I actually use another technique when I have both global set up and tear down.  I have a main method that calls my global setup, JUnitCore's runner and tear down.  This means I get a java class not a pure junit test.  But for integration tests, this has served me well.  And I still get the text runner output.